# Best approach to mobile web app security/authentication?

Tags: security, authentication, mobile

I'm working on a mobile web app solution for a company. It has several features which pull data from an internal SharePoint server using web services. It also connects to multiple databases on internal company servers. Everything is fine and dandy when I deploy the project from localhost (using my default credentials or someone else's).

But when it comes to an external device, I have no idea how to go about working on login authentication (using Active Directory) or security. Any advice on the best way to get started?

Comment: Look at [NTLM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLM).